# If $A$ and $ B$ be real invertible invertible matrices such that $AB=-BA$ then Trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ and $B$ be real invertible matrices such that $AB = - BA$. Then

1.$Trace(A)=Trace(B)=0$

2.$Trace(A)=Trace(B)=1$

3.$Trace(A)=0,Trace(B)=1$

4.$Trace(A)=1,Trace(B)=0$

$A$ is invertible $\Rightarrow$ $ABA^{-1}= -B$$\Rightarrow$ $B$ and $-B$ are similar. Hence $B$ and $-B$ have same eigenvalues which is possible only if $Trace(B)=0$ but still i am not getting proper reason to say that $Trace(B)=0$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eignevalue of $B$, then $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $-B$. Hence the sum of all eigenvalues of $B$ is zero, and this is exactly the trace.

Comment: You don't really need to mention eigenvalues for that: the fact that the trace is a linear map is elementary.

Answer (score 5):

What's non proper about your argument? In can be shortened a bit, though: since $B$ and $-B$ are similar, they have the same traces. Therefore $-\operatorname{tr}(B)=\operatorname{tr}(-B)=\operatorname{tr}(B)$ and so $\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$. By the same argument, $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

See $Tr(-B)$=$-Tr(B)$, $Tr(ABA^{-1})$=$Tr(B)$ So you have $Tr(B)=Tr(-B)=-Tr(B)$ and hence the result. Similarly $Tr(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use eigen values because you don't know if they have real eigen values and using complex eigen values seems overkill.

For example with $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
You have $BA = -AB$ with $A$ and $B$ invertible but $A$ doesn't have any real eigen values.

However, since $$\forall M,N \in M_n(\mathbb{R}), tr(MN) = tr(NM)$$
and $B = -ABA^{-1}$
$$tr(B) = tr(-ABA^{-1}) = -tr(ABA^{-1})= - tr(BA^{-1}A) = -tr(B)$$
therefore $tr(B) = 0$

Similarly $tr(A) = 0$

Comment: Once can *certainly* use eigenvalues, passing to the complex numbers.

Comment: @egreg I know but I don't know if OP knows about this possibility, and the point is you don't need to know anything about eigenvalues to prove this.

Comment: @egreg but I will edit to be clearer

Comment: Yes, the identity $\operatorname{tr}(MN)=\operatorname{tr}(NM)$ can be proved independently, but complex eigenvalues are useful nonetheless.

Comment: But if matrix B is of odd degree and B & -B are similar then 0 is one of the eigen value of B .But then B is not invertible which is contradiction to the given .where i am going wrong?

Comment: @dipalimali if $n$ is odd then no invertible matrix can satisfy the equality, you would have $det(B)det(A)=-det(B)det(A)$ which imply $det(A) = 0$ or $det(B) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$2\mathrm{trace}(B) = \sum_{\lambda \mathrm{\ eigenv \ of \ } B} \lambda + \sum_{\lambda \mathrm{\ eigenv \ of \ } -B} \lambda = \sum_{\lambda \mathrm{\ eigenv \ of \ } B} \lambda+\sum_{\lambda \mathrm{\ eigenv \ of \ } B} -\lambda = 0$$
That's because $B$ and $-B$ have opposite eigenvalues.