# Find $AB=-BA$ with not null product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given $A,B,\text{ both }2\times2$ matrices, find an example such that $AB=-BA$ with $AB\neq{0}$. I just can't find an example where that happens, it's easy to see where $AB=BA$ but no idea how to get the $(-1)$ scalar.

Comment: Do you mean $AB \neq 0$ instead?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, my bad, just edited it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337792/if-a-and-b-be-real-invertible-invertible-matrices-such-that-ab-ba-then-t

Comment: Great theorem, never seen it, i'm starting in linear algebra. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick
$$ A = \left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) $$
and

$$ B = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $$

Then

$$ AB = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $$
and

$$ BA = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $$

The intuition behind this answer is to exploit the property of anti-commutativity of reflection about the y-axis and rotation by 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Comment: Did you mean *anti*-commuting?  Similar intuition behind my answer

Comment: Oh yes. I will amend my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple example would be $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}0 &0 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Great! Thanks, it was kinda trivial, I might be tired, was trying with something like these hahaha!

Answer (score 2):

Try $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$.

Comment: Another nice and easy example, thanks.